# On a problem on the equation $a+b+c=n$.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $a,b,c,d,e,f\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ be six integers.
I want to prove that if $4$ distinct triples of them satisfy the equation $x+y+z=n$
then at least two of the $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are equal.

If two of the triples are distinct, wlog if
$$ a+b+c=n \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ e+f+g=n$$
then the third equation must contain at least two of $\{a,b,c\}$ or $\{e,f,g\}$ and so, again wlog,
$a+e+f=n$. But then $a=g$.
Similarly, it holds that any two of the triples do not intersect into two of the $a,b,c,d,e,f$. Any ideas, how to prove it in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You started strong, and just need to push through. With some thought, you should be able to fill in the details (or even come up with your own approach).

Proof by contradiction. Suppose no 2 integers are equal. Show that
1. No two triples are distinct. -> You shown this.
2. No two triples intersect at 2 element. -> You shown this.
3. Any two triples intersect at exactly 1 element. -> This follows from 1 and 2.
4. No three triples intersect at 1 element. -> This follows from 3.
5. There is a unique way (up to relabelling up the integers) to form the 4 triples. -> This follows from 3 and 4. $a+b+c = a+d+e = b+d+f = c+e+f$.
6. Each integer appears in exactly 2 triples.
7. The sum of all 6 integers is $ 2n$.
8. A triple, and its complement, have the same sum. This contradicts 1.

Answer (score 0):

$2+10+11=2+9+12=10+12+1$.

[$a=2,b=10,c=11,d=9,e=12,f=1$]

Comment: You are right! I meant to write "four" triples. Sorry.